# Check for new content with JS/PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have four tables: `projects`, `posts`, `users` and `project_users`. Some users are connected to some projects via the `project_users` table. Each project contains a bunch of rows from the `posts` table. Pretty straight forward.

The users can edit the posts rows and every time an update occurs the `user id` and `timestamp` should be saved so other users can see what is new and not. Should I save this information to 1) the post row, keeping a latest editor and time for each row or should I consider 2) a whole separate log table? What are the benefits of each case?

When that is decided, I want to run a script every now and then that refreshes the site content if any rows have been updated by anyone else (poor man's push). To give me some perspective. Is it a big query to ask the database with say 1 million posts: "check if there are any posts in this project where any user other than you have updated after timestamp `x`"? Just asking because I'd run that query a lot.

A much quicker way would be to log the latest editor to the projects or project users rows, but with multiple people editing at the same time, that would be less accurate and there is also no way to see which rows got updated. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks! But the project table only keep one editor and one date, which is good to know, but since I'm checking for updates every x seconds the refresh would be invalid if 2 people update too close to each other: User A updates, 5 seconds later user B updates, 5 seconds later user A updates again, 5 seconds later a script checks for updates for user A, but the script didn't run when user B was the latest editor so user A will miss that update.

Comment: The project users table contain the information about who is connected to which project so no need to put that in the user table.

Comment: okay then when ever the project is updated the users related to the project are notified this will prevent a situation were you have to run a script to check if an update has occurred. You can even use `SQL TRIGGERS` to pick up related user ID after an update has occurred and notify them.

Comment: How would you notify them? That requires push and websockets and stuff?

Comment: think of using `sql triggers` or in your php code `if (update successful){select where col=project_ID and col=user_ID and inform users}`

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea. But then lets ask my previous performance question again. What if the user table contains thousands of users, then every time an update is made it has to loop through and update a few of them? Maybe this is not an issue and indexing and all that is super speedy, just seem like a big operation to run every time something is changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165186/discussion-between-bobby-axe-and-seabass).

Answer (score 0):

Use solution (1). It's a clean design and easy to work with.

When you fetch `post` data for the edit form, save the `updated_at` timestamp in a hidden field. Then run an Ajax request every X seconds to check if the timestamp has been changed. The query is simple:

```
SELECT updated_at FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?
```

Since you filter by the primary key, the query will be very fast even with a huge table.

Now compare the fetched timestamp with what is stored in the hidden field. If it has changed - Notify the user (editor).

As you already realized, it's possible that another user will update the post between two Ajax requests. So you should also check for updates just befor saving the form data. Don't forget to use a transaction and lock the row:

Pseudo code:

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT updated_at FROM posts WHERE post_id = ? FOR UPDATE

if ($row->updated_at == $form->updated_at)
    then update row
    else notify the user that he is unlucky ;-(

COMMIT
```

Of course you can also use solution (2) and add a separate table `post_updates(post_id, user_id, updated_at)`. To get the latest timestamp you would run:

```
SELECT MAX(updated_at) as updated_at
FROM post_updates
WHERE post_id = ?
```

It should run pretty fast with an index on `(post_id, updated_at)`. But don't complicate things as long as you don't have any requirements which would benefit from that table.

Comment: Thanks! This is all great, but what if there are 100 posts, then I can’t go by primary key?

Comment: I thought you update one `post` at a time. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes you update one row at the time, but the user see a table with sometimes up to 100 rows that all should be up to date without having to refresh the page manually. I was unclear on that point.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. There is no big edit form, the whole table is editable and it saves with ajax per column. My javascript is checking every x seconds if there are any updated rows, which I wondered if it is a heavy task, since it will look for multiple rows belonging to a certain project with user id that is not your own and a timestamp newer than your last check. If it was a straight primary key check I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: I guess with "whole table" you mean all rows from one project. To check if any row has been updated, you only need to look at the latest one: `SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM posts WHERE project_id = ?`. Here you will need an index on `(post_id, updated_at)`. Or you can just fetch all updated rows: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE project_id = ? and updated_at > ?`. Anyway you never need to fetch all rows from the project.

Comment: Yes, that is true. So something like this? Do I need a LIMIT 1 too? SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM posts WHERE project_id = ? AND NOT updated_by = your_user_id

Comment: When you use `MAX()` without `GROUP BY` you will only get one row. So `LIMIT 1` would be superfluous. I would also not exclude the users changes from the result. I'd rather write the logic the way that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for the latest updated row that I didn't change myself. Otherwise I'll get into the trouble of missing other peoples changes again, or I'll re-load the content even if I made the change which also is a little wasteful. I'd love to just be able to update one single column and not look for other changes every time I update a field. That seems even slower to me? I totally get it if it was a form containing every column, but field per field edit I want to be as speedy as possible.

Comment: Well, when I think about it. I could potentially miss other peoples updates on the _same_ row anyway. So the solution would be to keep a timestamp and compare it to the latest updated row in the database, and if the row is newer then refresh the content, even if I made the edit and it's technically already up to date in the browser?

Comment: I also got a suggestion in chat to update everybody else's timestamp everytime a change is made. That makes a speedy check, but a bigger update every time a field is edited.